# Feeding std::streambuf for Non-Blocking std::istream Read

Tags: c++, stream-processing, blocking-function-call

I want to write small library to guide a child process for a specific needs (not trying to reinvent bicycle here).

My needs includes reading from child `stdout` and `stderr`. I want to implement this as streams. If I would use simple `std::streambuf` descendant that reads directly from pipe on `underflow` - then my stdout and stderr streams would block on read when there is no data available. I want to evade this, and so far I have two ideas

1. Provide a timeouted method for my streams, that checks if there any data. I need only binary interface of streams i.e. `read` and `write` methods, so method which which returns available data amount is fine enough.
2. But wait - there is already method, with behavior which almost match my desire. [std::streambuf::in_avail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/in_avail/). What if I'll start background thread which will feed data from pipes to my streambuf? Then I could use standard stream method [std::istream::readsome](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/readsome/).
3. Mix of a previous two: provide a method for streams, that will read data from pipe buffer to `streambuf`. Its like flush for `std::istream`. This eliminates need in a background thread.

Personally, I like the second variant better, but I feel, that it have many caveats.

Which variant is better in a terms of code readability, performance and interface usability?

Comment: how are you creating the child process? often there is a way to get its std streams and read/write to it.

Comment: The problem is - I want to provide `std::istream` objects for child std streams. Once library user call `child_stdout.read(1024)`, he wont gain control until child provide him 1024 bytes. But what if child will hang? Then parent will hang too, and there is no way to break this circle. Only with three separate threads: two to read `stdout` and `stderr` and one for watchdog to kill child on timeout and thus provide eof to streams. And I want to evade this.

Comment: The solution is then to use async IO which the `std::stream`s aren't suited to do.

Comment: Should I take a look on boost::asio then?

Comment: http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++/problem-with-streambuf/1004925

Answer (score 1):

It seems that like `ratchet freak` said in comments, the best solution is to use asynchronous IO. And i'm going to use `boost::asio`. It have nice support for pipes.

Windows: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html
Posix:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/stream_descriptor.html